# How to cast ostream to basic_ostream<unsigned char>?

Tags: c++

I have a method which accepts basic_ostream as parameter

```
write_sth_to( basic_ostream<unsigned char> &s );
```

Is there any way I can pass a std::cout (or any basic_ostream< char >) to it? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I mean write_sth_to( basic_ostream<unsigned char> &s );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I'd write a wrapper function to handle it, since you can't simply cast a `basic_ostream<char>` to a `basic_ostream<unsigned char>`. Something like the following might do the trick (note: untested code)

```
void wrapper(basic_ostream<char>& os)
{
    basic_stringstream<unsigned char> us;
    write_sth_to(us);
    transform(istream_iterator<unsigned char>(us),
              istream_iterator<unsigned char>(),
              ostream_iterator<char>(os, ""),
              char_to_unsigned_char
    );
}
```

where the function `char_to_unsigned_char` is something you write yourself (I don't know how you plan to convert between the two types). Remember this untested, but it may give you an idea of where to start.